# What is the main difference between configurations and environment variables in a software?

Tags: configuration, operating-system, environment-variables

What is the main difference between **configurations** and **environment variables** in a software?

For configurations in a conf-file, like *address*, *port*, and *file path*, they may be regarded as environment variables as well. But  for configurations like *dfs.namenode.audit.log.debug.cmdlist(A comma-separated list of NameNode commands that are written to the HDFS namenode audit log only if the audit log level is debug.)* in HDFS, should not be environment variables. In my opinion, both of configurations and environment variables are setting parameters for the software running environment. Therefore, configurations can be regarded as generalized environment variables. But there do exist some counterexamples. I want to know what's wrong with this idea and the difference between configurations and environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters for an application might be specified not just via configuration files or environment variables, but in other ways too, such as command-line arguments, the Windows Registry, or a database table.

I don't think it is useful to think of any one approach to be a generalisation of another approach. Instead, the different approaches are competing technologies. By Analogy, CDs competed against audio tapes and vinyl discs rather than being a generalisation of them.

It can be possible to integrate several competing technologies. For example, a music system might integrate a tape deck, turntable, CD player, radio and an AUX-in port (to connect to, say, an MP3 player) so you can enjoy music from any of several competing technologies. If you want to see an example of integrating several competing configuration technologies, I suggest you read Sections 2.5 and 3.5 of the *Config4* Getting Started Guide* to see how the [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/) configuration-file parser (developed by me) integrates with environment variables and command-line options.